# How to display the error and warning indicator on the left, next to the line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to move the indicator next to the line number, the same as on the [scroll bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biZlH.jpg)

[Like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLhYU.png)

I installed the Error Lens extension, but it's not what I need.
And I think this setting should be in the vscode itself, but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible- at least- not without extensions. and I think that could get visually confusing. scm diff decorations typically go there.